# How to print specific data based on its rank in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have data of cooking oil and its boiling temp and ranked it by highest boiling temp

```
print(df_ranked)

    ranking               oil  boil_temp
0         1           avocado        270
1         2         sunflower        252
2         3       beef_tallow        250
3         3  butter_clarified        250
4         3           mustard        250
5         4              palm        235
6         5              corn        230
7         6         grapeseed        216
8         7            canola        204
9         8           coconut        200
10        9          olive_ev        160
11       10            butter        150
```

I used print function to print data with certain rank and this is the result

```
print(df_ranked.loc[df_ranked['ranking'].isin([3])])

 ranking               oil  boil_temp
2        3       beef_tallow        250
3        3  butter_clarified        250
4        3           mustard        250
```

I want the result to be more simple like this

```
beef_tallow, 250
butter_clarified, 250
mustard, 250
```

or this

```
Oil with third highest boiling temperature: beef_tallow, butter_clarified, mustard
```

I tried using loop to get result like that, but the code I used seems to be wrong because it didn't print anything

```
for i in df_ranked['ranking'].items():
  for x in df_ranked['oil'].items():
    if (i==3):
       print(f'Oil with third highest boiling temperature:{x}')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If need all joined values first aggregate `join` and then loop in `Series`:

```
s = df.groupby('ranking')['oil'].agg(', '.join)
print (s)
1                                    avocado
2                                  sunflower
3     beef_tallow, butter_clarified, mustard
4                                       palm
5                                       corn
6                                  grapeseed
7                                     canola
8                                    coconut
9                                   olive_ev
10                                    butter
Name: oil, dtype: object
Oil with 1 highest boiling tem

for i, v in s.items():
    print(f'Oil with {i} highest boiling temperature:{v}')
```

If need both columns join them and loop in `groupby` object:

```
g = df[['oil','boil_temp']].astype(str).agg(', '.join, axis=1).groupby(df['ranking'])

for i, v in g:
    print(f"Oil with {i} highest boiling temperature:")
    print('\n'.join(v))
Oil with 1 highest boiling temperature:
avocado, 270
Oil with 2 highest boiling temperature:
sunflower, 252
Oil with 3 highest boiling temperature:
beef_tallow, 250
butter_clarified, 250
mustard, 250
Oil with 4 highest boiling temperature:
palm, 235
Oil with 5 highest boiling temperature:
corn, 230
Oil with 6 highest boiling temperature:
grapeseed, 216
Oil with 7 highest boiling temperature:
canola, 204
Oil with 8 highest boiling temperature:
coconut, 200
Oil with 9 highest boiling temperature:
olive_ev, 160
Oil with 10 highest boiling temperature:
butter, 150
```

Comment: for once we got one use case each ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
s = (df_ranked.loc[df_ranked['ranking'].isin([3]), ['oil', 'boil_temp']]
              .astype(str).agg(', '.join, axis=1)
     )
# 2         beef_tallow, 250
# 3    butter_clarified, 250
# 4             mustard, 250
# dtype: object

print('\n'.join(s))
```

output:

```
beef_tallow, 250
butter_clarified, 250
mustard, 250
```